# How to iterate through all facts in a predicate?

Tags: prolog

Lets say I have a database with:

```
holds(p1,b1).
holds(p2,b1).
holds(p3,b1).
```

I want to have a predicate that can check all the holds statements from the database without me having to type holds(X,b1) 3 times in case I don't know before hand how many are in the database.

Comment: What do you mean by "check all holds statements"?

Comment: Check all the holds statements from the database. Basically in my predicate I want to do "holds(X,b1),  doSomething(X)". But I want to do it on p1,p2,p3 in a single predicate. It should also work no matter the number of facts in the database.

Comment: *I want to have a predicate that can check all the holds statements from the database*. What do you mean by "check"? Can you please give an example of a query you want to enter and what results you want, specifically?

Answer (score 3):

[forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)/2 should be appropriate for your needs

```
?- forall(holds(X,b1), doSomething(X)).
```

Beware that doSomething(X) should succeed. If your Prolog doesn't have it, the implementation (from SWI-prolog library) is quite compact :

```
%%  forall(+Condition, +Action)
%
%   True if Action if true for all variable bindings for which Condition
%   if true.

forall(Cond, Action) :-
    \+ (Cond, \+ Action).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findall/3` to find all of the values that would satisfy `holds(X,b1)`; then you can go through that list and do whatever you need to for each.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do it without a system predicate?